# Combining two queries sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how to combine the following queries

QUERY 1

```
SELECT hotel.country, time.year, time.month, COUNT(booking.room_id) as booked 

FROM booking 
LEFT JOIN room on room.room_id = booking.room_id 

LEFT JOIN hotel on room.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id 

LEFT JOIN time on booking.time_id = time.time_id 

GROUP BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month 

ORDER by hotel.country, time.year, time.month
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT hotel.country, time.year, time.month, COUNT(checkout.room_id) as checkedout

FROM checkout

LEFT JOIN room on room.room_id = checkout.room_id

LEFT JOIN hotel on room.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id

LEFT JOIN time on checkout.time_id = time.time_id

GROUP BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month

ORDER BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month
```

I expect output as below

Country, year, month, booking count, checkout count, sum(booking+checkout)

Any suggestions?

Comment: UNION ALL. Aggregate.

Comment: Why the outer joins? Do bookings and checkouts exist where `room_id` or `hotel_id` or `time_id` are null? That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: looking for union???

Comment: As `booking` refers to a certain `time`, I surmise that this is the time when the booking was made and not for when it was made (because that would be a time *range* instead). Correct? So we may find months that have bookings and no checkouts and also months that have checkouts and no bookings. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

Using a mysql Union with aggregate.

union docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html
aggregate docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

example of union below:

```
SELECT 
    firstName, 
    lastName
FROM
    employees 
UNION 
SELECT 
    contactFirstName, 
    contactLastName
FROM
    customers;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.country, 
       T1.year, 
       T1.month,
       T1.booked,
       T2.checkedout, 
      (T1.booked + T2.checkedout) AS 'sum(booking+checkout)'
FROM 
(
SELECT hotel.country, time.year, time.month, COUNT(booking.room_id) as booked 

FROM booking 
LEFT JOIN room on room.room_id = booking.room_id 

LEFT JOIN hotel on room.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id 

LEFT JOIN time on booking.time_id = time.time_id 

GROUP BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month 

ORDER by hotel.country, time.year, time.month
) AS T1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT hotel.country, time.year, time.month, COUNT(checkout.room_id) as checkedout

FROM checkout

LEFT JOIN room on room.room_id = checkout.room_id

LEFT JOIN hotel on room.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id

LEFT JOIN time on checkout.time_id = time.time_id

GROUP BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month

ORDER BY hotel.country, time.year, time.month
)AS T2
ON T1.country=T2.country
AND T1.year=T2.year
AND T1.month=T2.month
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to solving this uses `UNON ALL`:

```
SELECT h.country, t.year, t.month, SUM(is_booking) as booked, SUM(is_checkout) as checkedout
FROM ((SELECT b.room_id, b.time_id, 1 as is_booking 0 as is_checkout
       FROM booking b
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT c.room_id, c.time_id, 0 as is_booking, 1 as is_checkout
       FROM checkout c
      )
     ) bc  LEFT JOIN
     room r
     ON r.room_id = bc.room_id LEFT JOIN
     hotel h
     ON r.hotel_id = h.hotel_id LEFT JOIN
     time t
     ON bc.time_id = t.time_id 
GROUP BY h.country, t.year, t.month 
ORDER by h.country, t.year, t.month
```